# JavaScript Get all Loaded Scripts

Tags: javascript, dynamic, load

I am trying to create a Javascript function that will return all javascript files loaded.  For Example:

I load jquery.js, jquery.somescript.js, and tinymce.js

I want a function to return everything in script format (so if I were to save and run the return text again) it would work just as if I had called the files described above.  Also if TinyMCE loads 15 JS fies, it should return as well.

I hope that isn't too confusing to understand, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName) should get you started:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
// TODO: loop and read the src attribute
```

Comment: That will provide access to the elements, but (as far as I know) not to the actual Javascript source code contained in the scripts. It might be possible to read the contents from same-origin scripts, but not from scripts fetched from other servers. (I think.) (Actually, I really really hope ...)

Comment: That is close, but I think what would be better is to just do a (using jQuery):

$.get("script url",function(value){...});

Thanks Though!

Comment: "document.scripts" is built directly into the DOM and returns all script elements.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure exactly what you are trying to do but it sounds as if you are wanting one .js file to instead of many. I think you would be making more work for yourself to do that in a script. Just view the source for all of the script files and append then to one file. Save that then call that file as your src.