# How to collect all script tags of HTML page in a variable

Tags: javascript, html, html-parsing

I would like to collect all the `<script> ....</script>` code section present in the HTML page in some variable.

What should be the simpler way to do this, Any idea how it can be retrieved using JavaScript.??

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: You mean *using a JavaScript script*, aren't you?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160609/javascript-get-all-loaded-scripts

Comment: @SimeonVisser with the script variable containing all scripts I want to show the links of the scripts to github on my [website](tik9.github.io) to show the users how I use scripts on my site.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

To get a list of scripts you can use

- `document.getElementsByTagName("script");` by tag
- `document.scripts;` Built-in collection
- `document.querySelectorAll("script");` by selector
- `$("script")` jQuery by selector

```js
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
  if (scripts[i].src) console.log(i, scripts[i].src)
  else console.log(i, scripts[i].innerHTML)
}

// To get the content of the external script 
// - I use jQuery here - only works if CORS is allowing it

// find the first script from google 
var url = $("script[src*='googleapis']")[0].src; 

$.get(url,function(data) { // get the source 
  console.log(data.split("|")[0]); // show version info
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  console.log("Inline script");
</script>
<script>
  function bla() {
    console.log("Other inline script");
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 11):

The simplest way is probably `document.scripts`

Answer (score 1):

You would do:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName( 'script' );
```

Now `scripts` is a NodeList (like an array), and you can access each one using `scripts[0]`, `scripts[1]` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
```

Comment: It does not return an `Array`

Comment: Typing or spelling mistake. It is getElements, not getElement, but it has been answered in depth elsewhere on this page too :)

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery :

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
```

With jQuery :

```
var scripts = $("script");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go --

```
(function () { 
        'use strict';
        let logscript = function () {
            let js = document.scripts;
            for (let i = 0; i < js.length; i++) {
                if (js[i].src) {
                        console.log(i, js[i].src);
                    } else {
                        console.log(i, js[i].innerHTML);
                }   
            }
        };
        if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
                logscript();
        } else {
                window.addEventListener('load', logscript);
        }
})();
```