# get scripts by tag name under IE 8

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname

When I try to get for example all images using

```
getElementsByTagName('img');
```

there is no problems, but when I try to get all scripts

```
getElementsByTagName('script');
```

the function returns empty value. This problem exists only under IE8.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is just a wild guess but are the script tags in the <head></head> tags or <body></body> tags? I don't know if this has any relevance to the problem, but it's a possibility??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I checked it and this is working fine in all browser.

`getElementsByTagName('script')` return an object.  For chrome it returns as `NodeList[]`, whereas in IE8 it returns as `[object HTMLCollection]`.

I'm not sure whether you are trying to access the `src` of the `script` used in your project.  If so, try the below code

```
window.onload=function() {
  var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
  for (var i=0;i<scripts.length;i++) {
     if (scripts[i].src) console.log(i,scripts[i].src)
     else console.log(i,scripts[i].innerHTML)
  }
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078654/how-to-collect-all-script-tags-of-html-page-in-a-variable).

Comment: Yes, it *should* work like that; however in IE8 I have a case where `document.getElementsByTagName('script')` results in a collection of inline `script`s, but it fails to return `script`s with external `src`.