# How to load HTML and corresponding CSS / JS using Ajax?

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

Getting the HTML I need through Ajax is not a problem, I just use the jQuery [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function But I have no clue on how to get the corresponding CSS and javascript for that HTML.

Is there a way to just get the ***style*** and ***script*** tag from that page and append it to my page?

*Note: I'm working on the same domain, so no cross-domain calls*

Thanks !

Comment: This should be of service http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078654/how-to-collect-all-script-tags-of-html-page-in-a-variable

Comment: You might need to do inline styling

Comment: why you need to fetch those style and script. because as soon as response comes to your calling page; it will get attached to your DOM and style and script will get automatically available there.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

In data.html

```
<link href="my.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

In index.html

```
<script>
    $.get('data.html', function(data) {
        $(document.head).append(data);
    }, 'html');
</script>
```